What is the stance of Buddhism on discussing philosophies, beliefs, ideas, and practices of other religions or belief systems?
What are the rules or guidelines on how a Buddhist should engage with others who would like to discuss philosophies, beliefs, ideas, and practices of other religions or belief systems?

Are Buddhists allowed to discuss / engage in the ideas to some degree? Or is it shunned.
How does Buddhism incorporate ideas outside the main canon / system? (Generally speaking)
Are certain topics to be never discussed?

This would help me ask better questions to the Buddhism community in general, but also would serve as a gauge as to how to interact. Basically, what is acceptable conversation topics in the end.

Are Buddhists allowed to discuss / engage in the ideas to some degree? Or is it shunned.
"Allowed" implies a moral precept -- of which there are at least five in Buddhism -- one of which is to refrain from incorrect speech.
Wikipedia summarizes that as


The fourth precept involves falsehood spoken or committed to by action, as well as malicious speech, harsh speech and gossip.


Access to Insight has a page about "Right Speech" which I recommend as relevant, with extracts from the suttas.
Buddhist monks live with a lot of additional rules, and there may be rules of etiquette about how you should talk with them.
Famous contemporary monks like the Dalai Lama and Thich Nhat Hanh had "interfaith dialogs".
On this stack exchange site there are a few comparative-religion topics but the rule is that the topic should be at least as much about Buddhism -- e.g. a question like "What do Buddhist think of Nietzsche?" might be closed as off-topic.
How does Buddhism incorporate ideas outside the main canon / system? (Generally speaking)
It may vary, depending on the tradition/school/sect.
For example Theravada (the "way of the elder monks") tries to be traditional e.g. as based on the Early Buddhist Texts.
Other traditions for example Mahayana (which I think means, "the great way" or "the way for everyone") may adopt somewhat -- for example Zen or Chan is said to have elements of or to have been influenced by Daoism, or for example Tibetan might seem to include elements of Hinduism.
Wikipedia's Buddhism in Vietnam starts by calling it syncretic,

Buddhism in Vietnam (Vietnamese: Đạo Phật, 道佛 or Phật Giáo, 佛教), as practiced by the Vietnamese people, is a form of East Asian Mahayana Buddhism. It is the main religion in Vietnam. Vietnamese Buddhism is generally inclusive and syncretic, drawing on the main Chinese Buddhist traditions, such as Tiantai (Vietnamese: Thiên Thai) and Huayan (Hoa Nghiêm), Zen (Thiền), and Pure Land (Tịnh Độ).
Buddhism may have first come to Vietnam as early as the 3rd or 2nd century BCE from the Indian subcontinent or from China in the 1st or 2nd century CE.Vietnamese Buddhism has had a syncretic relationship with certain elements of Taoism, Chinese spirituality, and Vietnamese folk religion. Theravada Buddhism also exists, as well as indigenous forms of Vietnamese Buddhism such as Bửu Sơn Kỳ Hương and Hòa Hảo.

Are certain topics to be never discussed?
According to the suttas there were topics which the Buddha wouldn't discuss i.e. questions he wouldn't answer:

The unanswerable questions

If you ask one of these questions on this site, the answer is likely to be that, "The Buddha didn't answer that".
I think there was also at least one instance -- I don't remember the reference -- where the Buddha kept silent because the answer would have only confused the person.
Related to "topics which shouldn't be talked about", there are topics which shouldn't be thought about -- see e.g. this page which describes Right View.

Buddhists are allowed to talk about religions (because the Buddha did) however it should ideally be for the purpose of helping others align with a path of liberation &/or a path of morality  (efficacy of deeds). In other words, discussion should accord with Right Speech, which is truthful, pleasant, cordial, timely & beneficial. For example, while a Buddhist would avoid quarrelling & heated &/or lengthy arguments, Buddhism would not support any non-kammic religious doctrines based on identity &/or faith alone, such as Caste Brahmanism/Hinduism, Lutheranism or Biblical rationales for Zionism.
Buddhism is a complete path therefore requires no incorporation of external ideas. In DN 16, the Buddha declared his Teaching was complete, with nothing hidden or withheld. Buddhists who seek external ideas obviously do not know the entire scope of the Buddha's teachings.

Buddhists are generally allowed to discuss and engage with ideas from other belief systems. In fact, many schools of Buddhism have historically incorporated aspects of other philosophical or spiritual traditions, adapting and integrating them in various ways. For example, Buddhist philosophy has interacted with Hinduism, Taoism, Confucianism, and also modern Western psychology. Buddhism is the concept of nature so it's a way of living. To believe in nature, existence, karma, purifying peace to reach higher state of mind and to final enlightenment. To follow the path Lord Buddha has guided us.
